# TypeError: object supporting the buffer API required in flask api

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, flask

i have this code which i want to convert the password into md5

```
class UserLogin(Resource):
    def post(self):

            # Parse the arguments

            parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
            parser.add_argument('username')
            parser.add_argument('password')
            args = parser.parse_args()

            _user = args['username']
            _userPassword = args['password']
            _h = hashlib.md5(_userPassword.encode())
            conn = mysql.connect()
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute('''select * from user where username = %s && password = %s''', (_user, _h))
            data = cursor.fetchall()

            return jsonify(data)
```

but the error says: h = hashlib.md5(_userPassword.encode())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'

and when i remove the encode() from hashlib, the error return is:_h = hashlib.md5(_userPassword)
TypeError: object supporting the buffer API required

please help me. im using python3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
_h = hashlib.md5(_userPassword.encode())
```

you might want

```
_h = hashlib.md5(_userPassword.encode()).hexdigest()
```

And if you're storing the MD5 hash of the password, the

```
password = md5(%s)
```

part the query isn't going to match it if you bind `_h`.

Comment: im sorry i forgot to edit it coz password = md5(%s)''',(_user,_userPassword) wont work either. thats why i need to use hashlib and still your answer returns an error says no attribute 'encode' thanks for your answer.

Comment: If you're getting a 'no attribute' error, you left off the parenthesis. But if `... password = md5(%s)", (..., _userPassword))` isn't working, you may have a deeper problem.

Comment: Yes sir dave, i found out already the problem. :) It was on my system. :) I reinstalled my os and the query worked with md5(%s). Thanks a lot. You gave me some idea that it has a deeper problem and i reinstall ubuntu :) and it solved. Thanks again. Sorry, I replied late :)